# Electrum - low fee

Tags: wallet, e-wallet

Please help! I received .116 BitCoin into my Electrum account and then sent .115 BitCoin to my Dream market account. Annoyingly a low fee has appeared on Electrum (see screenshot).

[image]

I added another .0108 BitCoin to the Electrum account, believing it will force the payment through as there would be enough balance to see it through - but to no avail!The message I'm getting on Dream market is 'You have a pending incoming deposit of ฿0.115. The confirmation takes 20 minutes (2 confirmations) in average.' (see screenshot 2)
[image]

Is there a way to either cancel this payment and retry and force it through as it's been 27 hours now and I don't think that this'll right itself?

I've read other BitCoin forums with similar problems to what I'm experiencing, but I'm a real novice and reading some of the replies is like learning a completely different language.

Any easy solution with basic step-by-step guide would be much appreciated